# Updating and moving column rows based on matching data

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I don't think I explained well so I want to start the discussion again with a better explanation.

There are 4 columns A/B are tied together C/D as well.

The `THER_CLASS` column is the first 6 digits of the `key` column.

If you look at the 1st row A you see 011000 this is associated with all of the key rows where the 1st 6 numbers are the same (011000):

[image]

I want row A and B copied for all associated key/GPI numbers and then move on to the next one (012000):

[image]

As you can see, what was column 2 is now column 16 because it moved down.

Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fm55PQhpN1vm3j57pD87hJvet-toHYpreIWpm1oKdPI/pubhtml

Comment: What is your question? And remember "How do I do this?" is too broad.

Comment: My question is how to make image 1 look like image 2 for every unique THER_CLASS number.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, trying to be clear. Rows 3 and beyond should be moved to row 16 (where they have the same 6 characters) . And then A2 and B2 should be copied all the way down through 15.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, what have you tried to this point and specifically what is your sticking point on the code you have tried to write?

Comment: @ScottCraner I was writing a c# application to do this and my boss said I was overdoing it and to just do it in excel :|

Comment: Tell your boss that it would need to be written in vba and you need to take classes to learn this new skill, which cost money, and see how quickly he/she lets you use c#. :)  I would put Columns A:B in another sheet and use VLOOKUP: In A2: `=VLOOKUP(Left(C2,6),Sheet2!A:B,1,False)` where sheet2 is the name of the sheet where you put the data.  And for B2 change the `1` to `2`.

Comment: @ScottCraner lol, please put this as answer it worked.

Comment: I made it a little more dynamic.  One formula to drag over and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste your current columns A:B to another sheet, then use VLOOKUP:

In A2 put:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT($C2,6),Sheet2!$A:$B,COLUMN(A:A),FALSE)
```

Where `Sheet2` is the sheet in which you pasted the data from the original.

Copy/drag over on column and down the length of the data.